# Divisors that are not perfect squares

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of positive divisors of $2015^8$ that are not perfect squares. I factorized it and started counting with the rule the resulting power of the factor must not be a perfect square. But the counting is becoming difficult.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to count the total number of positive divisors and subtract the total number of perfect square divisors.  Every positive divisor is of the form
$$5^i\cdot 13^j\cdot 31^k$$ with $i,j,k\in\{0,\ldots,8\}$.  There are 9 choices for each of $i,j,k$ which results in $9^3$ possible factors.  Every perfect square divisor is of the form
$$5^{2l}\cdot 13^{2m}\cdot 31^{2n}$$ with $l,m,n\in\{0,\ldots,4\}$.  How many possibilities are there here?

Answer (score 1):

$2015$ has $3$ distinct prime factors: $5,13,31$.

Hence the total number of divisors of $2015^8$ is $(8+1)^3=729$.

The divisors that are perfect squares are those in which each factor is raised to an even power.

In other words, each one of the factors should be raised to either one of the exponents $0,2,4,6,8$.

So we have $5^3=125$ divisors that are perfect squares, and $729-125=604$ divisors that are not.